# Spring webflow demo application

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I am new to Spring and webflow.
I was looking for some demo application and someone suggested me to look at petclinicplus 
@ http://code.google.com/p/petclinicplus/.

But I do not know how to download the project? I can see that it allows svn checkout.
I also dont know svn, but I tried to downloaded svn and executed 
svn checkout http://petclinicplus.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ petclinicplus-read-only

however it is not working.

Is there any other way to download?

Cheers

Comment: there's no bundled project... but why svn fail ?

Comment: there was some "can not access" error.. but now that I tried again, it worked. cant believe. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

Examples are bundled with the source. You can sownload Spring Webflow from springsource.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can browse the booking application online here:

https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-webflow

Getting started can be tricky, but I recommend this blog as a quick simple boot-up point:

http://jee-bpel-soa.blogspot.com/2008/12/building-spring-web-flows-2.html

Answer (score 0):

Spring Web Flow samples on GitHub:

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-webflow-samples